# How open Image in full Screen when we click on any image in list in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Here I want to open `image` in full screen when I click  on any `particular` `image` which I set in `GridView.builder() widget`. So When I `click` on 1st image it `display` on other screen as full screen `image`. So, how I accomplish this?

I get list of `image` through `APIs` in `GridView.builder()`. So, how to `open` particular `image` on full screen when I `click` on any `particular image`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get full screen image easily by following the below code.Also,bonus: Hero animation. 
Hope this helps

```
GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.push(context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) {
                return FullScreenImage(
                  imageUrl:
                  imageUrlHere,
                  tag: "generate_a_unique_tag",
                );
              }));
        },
        child: Hero(
          child: YourImageView,
          tag: "generate_a_unique_tag",
        ),
      ),
```

I have used cached_network_image 2.0.0 for caching and displaying image

```
class FullScreenImage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String imageUrl;
  final String tag;

  const FullScreenImage({Key key, this.imageUrl, this.tag}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black87,
      body: GestureDetector(
        child: Center(
          child: Hero(
            tag: tag,
            child: CachedNetworkImage(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              fit: BoxFit.contain,
              imageUrl: imageUrl,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.pop(context);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Will there be two files or a single dart file? Can you share the complete code or little bit of explanation?

Comment: A dart file for FullScreenImage. And you can just use that widget like shown above in the first snippet

Comment: Thanks for the comment. So, basically i need to put everything in single file.

Comment: You can do that as well. Not necessarily

Comment: i need to dig more. Its little bit confusing to me due to lack of knowledge. Can't define a const constructor for a class with non-final fields.
Try making all of the fields final, or removing the keyword 'const' from the constructor.

Answer (score -2):

u can use package in pub.dev called
full_screen_image_null_safe 2.0.0 icon indicating copy to clipboard operation
it's Url for package:
https://pub.dev/packages/full_screen_image_null_safe